# Is there someway I could insert data in MSSQL using PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server-2005

Is there someway I could insert data in MSSQL using PHP ?

Here is the code for mysql , what changes could be done to insert data in MSSQL instead .. Thank You

```
<?php

$where_form_is="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].strrev(strstr(strrev($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),"/"));

include("config.inc.php");
$link = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
if(!$link) die ('Could not connect to database: '.mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);
$query = "INSERT into `".$db_table."` (field_1,field_2,field_3,field_4) VALUES ('" . $_POST['field_1'] . "','" . $_POST['field_2'] . "','" . $_POST['field_3'] . "','" . $_POST['field_4'] . "')";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close($link);

include("confirm.html");

?>
```

Comment: I think you can do it. Please visit [this link of php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php)

Comment: Use PDO. It abstracts many of the database differences. Also, beware of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sqlsrv_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) instead of mysql_connect but I would highly recommend using PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php if you're jumping between databases.

```
// Create connection
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpres";
$connOptions = array("UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password", "Database"=>"dbname");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connOptions );

// catch if connection isn't vaild
if( $conn === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Prepare query
$sql = "INSERT INTO Table_1 (id, data) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
$params = array($_POST['field_1'], $_POST['field_2'], $_POST['field_3'], $_POST['field_4']);

// Run query and catch if it fails
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
if( $stmt === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Close the connection.
sqlsrv_close( $conn );
```

edit: added four values to statement